Are self described Reform and Conservative Jews assumed to be halachically Jewish according to Orthodox Judaism?
I’m curious about what the Orthodox understanding of Halacha says about whether Reform and Conservative people are still assumed to be halachically Jewish.
Obviously the overwhelming majority of them are not observant of Halacha or even Shomer Shabbat according to Orthodox standards, however a Reform or Conservative Jew who was raised as such from birth has the din of tinok shenishba (lit. 'captive infant', i.e. held to be unaccountable for their lack of Jewish knowledge/practice).
There are several factors though why many people that identify as Reform and Conservative Jews might have the status of non-Jews according to Orthodox understanding of halacha, including intermarriage being widespread in both movements and sanctioned officially by the Reform movement, the Reform movement accepting patrilineal descent, the Reform and Conservative movements both perform conversions not recognized by Orthodox halacha (with very few exceptions) and the like.
So should it still be assumed that somebody who says that they're Reform or Conservative is a Jew according to an Orthodox understanding of halacha, or not?

"So should it still be assumed that somebody who says" ... assumed as far as what? Giving your daughter's hand in marriage, counting in a minyan, invited over for kiddush, invited over for a meal on Y"T? You may need to clarify towards what end, because there isn't necessarily a one size fits all answer to this...

Is anyone assumed Jewish without asking basic questions?

Jewish status is a case-by-case basis. Are you trying to argue that the members of the movements as a whole must be ousted?

And what about a person raised "orthodox" who now identifies as reform, or even as non-Jewish?  I do not believe religious observance is the touchstone of whether somebody is or is not Jewish.

@stevenachman I think you misunderstood the question. I think the question was whether the subset of Reform/Conservative individuals who are not halachically Jewish (e.g. not Jewish via matrilineal descent, or converted Reform, etc.) is large enough such that you cannot halachically presume (utilizing principles of chazaka and rov) based solely on Reform/Conservative affiliation that the individual in question is halachically Jewish without obtaining more information about the matrilineal descent or conversion of the individual in question.

One should not in general assume anything. When marrying people or in questions of aliyah, even for people from orthodox background, some rabbies seek confirmantion to verify that prospective bride and groom are Jewish. There is high demand for archive workers in Eastern Europe from American Jews doing genealogical research with this specific reason.

@YDJ Sometimes you can assume things.  When you walk into a shul you've never been to, they'll count you for a minyan and nobody asks for proof that you're Jewish.
